# retrieve closest tree to input tree with k nearest neighbor?

Tags: search, data-structures, machine-learning, nearest-neighbor, knn

I want to use K-nearest neighbor approach to retrieve closest tree  to input tree from data set. The node in tree have value but branches in each tree do not have label.

for example:

Tree 1: (S (V c)
    (N (P y))
    (V (V o)
      (N (D t) (N d))))

Tree 2: (S
    (V (V p)
      (P (R o))
      (N (D t) (N d))))

I want to use k-nearest neighbor for this problem. Are you have any idea to use this approach for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define a distance measure for trees to apply `KNN` algorithm. There are many possible metrices for trees to use, one of the most popular choices is **tree edit distance**
( [How do I calculate tree edit distance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065247/how-do-i-calculate-tree-edit-distance) )

KNN **is not** a search algorithm. It is not used for finding the closest object, but rather - classifing object to one of the predefined labels. It simply searches for K nearest neighbours of given point X, and returns a label which have most of the neighbours.

For finding a closest tree, assuming that you already have defined the `TED` (tree edit distance) would be simply iterate through all `tree` in `trees` and select the one that minimizes `TED(tree,X)`.

Very good resource regarding Tree Edit Distance is also located here:
http://www.inf.unibz.it/dis/projects/tree-edit-distance/tree-edit-distance.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If i use tree edit distance, How(or where) i use KNN algorithm?

Comment: updated answer = KNN is not a search algorithm, but rather - a supervised classification model

Comment: I know KNN is for classification but I want to find a way to use it for finding closest tree.

Comment: But you can not, this would be like "I know that this function is for counting number of letters 'a' but I want it to paint a happy face". `KNN` is not a search tool. Your problem can be (and should be) solved by one simple for loop. Of course from the theoretical point of view, you can create a training set in form of `(X,X)` (input is also a label, or `(X,Xid)` where `Xid` is `X`'s identifier), and ask a `KNN` with `K`=1 for a label, and it will return the closest tree, but **do not do it**, it would be highly artificial, inefficient and weird... yet possible.

Comment: ok, thanks. How I can find a closest tree that it is like the input tree from root to leaf nodes? (I have 3 trees: tree 1 and tree 2 have similar leaf but the internal nodes are different. and tree 1 and tree 3 have different leaf but similar internal nodes. I want to use an algorithm to select tree 3 for tree 1.)

Comment: You need to define `TED` accordingly, so that cost of edition near the root is smaller then the one on the deeper levels.